# How do I format an integer with thousands separators and no decimals in a Power BI measure?

Tags: powerbi

How do I format a measure that contains integers with thousands separators and without decimals in a Power BI measure?

For example:
1200 should display as 1,200
and 874 should display as   874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Measure tools, and configure the measure formatting like this:

[image]

Comment: Those toolbar formatting options are unavailable since the model comes from an external source.  The formatting needs to be done with a FORMAT statement. For some reason this does not work. VendorCount:=FORMAT(DISTINCTCOUNT([DimVendorID]),"#,##0;(#,##0)")

Comment: You can create local measures in a report doing Live Connect to a shared Dataset.